# Blender animations move character down halfway below terrain in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-physics, blender

I have a character made in blender together with some basic animations. When i drag the character prefab inside my scene in Unity and press play the character clips halfway down in the terrain. When i disable the "Animator" from the prefab the character does not clip down, but stays in its given position. It also rotates the character 90 degrees.

How can i fix so that the animations made in blender does not move down or rotates my character? I will provide images of the issue together with values from the inspector.[image: Character when cliped down in terrain]

[image: Character before hitting play]

[image: Values for the character from the inspector]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the animation clip(s) and click "Bake Into Pose" under "Root Transform Position (Y)" do that for Root Transform Rotation aswell

[image]